# what is "php://input"? It mainly seen in webservice

Tags: php

What is the relevance of `php://input` in the following snippet, and what is it used for?

```
$json_string = GPTake(array('json_string'));
$handle = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);

$test = json_decode($jsonInput);
```

Answer (score 11):

It gives you direct access to the input stream, as opposed to accessing the data after PHP has already applied the `$_GET`/`$_POST` super globals. Also, according to the manual, it is both less intensive and allows you to grab information before any **php.ini** directives have been applied.

For more information, read the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) on `php://input`

Answer (score 8):

`php://` is a scheme wrapper around various input/output streams that PHP supports. You can read up for here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php.

Specifically, `php://input` allows you to read the input stream directly.

Answer (score -3):

read following

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php