# getting array input from ios and android devices and have to write differnet code for both

Tags: php, ios

I am using the following code for getting array from iOs developer those are using my webservices.

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
```

and i want to create the same for android then i use

`$_POST` and get the array input .

what is the common way to get the array input . So that no need to write two different code.

and ios developer using the following code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WEB_URL]];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"username",@"username",@"password",@"password",textboxMobile.text,@"mobile",textboxEmail.text,@"email",deviceidnew,@"device_id",cityid,@"city_id",[NSString stringWithFormat: @""],@"othercity",areaidstore,@"area_id",[NSString stringWithFormat: @""],@"otherarea",self.textboxName.text,@"name",khidmatarraylist,@"khidmat_id",userid,@"user_id",@"editprofileiphone",@"tag",nil];         

        SBJSON *parser =[[SBJSON alloc] init];
        NSString *jsonString = [parser stringWithObject:dict];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

I checked these links:

[what is "php://input"? It mainly seen in webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656596/what-is-php-input-it-mainly-seen-in-webservice)

[I am sending dictionary in json and its have two array and multiple value but i am getting response access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971265/i-am-sending-dictionary-in-json-and-its-have-two-array-and-multiple-value-but-i)

but not that much help full
any suggestion ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you what to pass an array from an application to the web server?

Comment: yes basically i am creating web service part . and i take ios code from them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess You are missing this at iOS side,

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: we have added the content type but not worked. can i have a reference link for sending array or dictionary to any webservice .